# How to color only numbers and special characters in a Microsoft Excel cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, colors, microsoft-excel-2016, conditional-formatting

Is it possible to color only numbers and special characters of a cell (or column) by conditional formatting or some other similar method?

I have created a book in Excel to organize my passwords (or to put my passwords in order before exporting them to a password manager). Then, in the "passwords" column, I would like Excel to color the numbers and special characters to distinguish them from the rest of the text.

[Example: Enpass 6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BwEs7.png)

I saw this in the application Enpass 6 (beta) and I liked the effect, and I do not know if you can implement something similar in Excel.

[Example: Microsoft Excel 2016](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JaFhQ.png)

Thank you very much for any recommendation or idea.

Ps 1: Annex screenshots of Enpass and the effect that I would like to see in Excel, for example the numbers have one color and the special characters another color.

Ps 2: I note that I am not so expert programming, so if you recommend a Visual Basic code, please with your comments to try to understand.

Ps 3: thank you very much for your help, again.

Comment: vba is the only way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to SuperUser. VBA isn't as scary as it may seem at first, and this a great project to start to understand some functions.

First, you should [enable the Developer Tab in Excel](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/show-the-developer-tab-e1192344-5e56-4d45-931b-e5fd9bea2d45#ID0EAABAAA=Newer_Versions).

1 - Click the File tab.

2 - Click Options.

3 - Click Customize Ribbon.

4- Under Customize the Ribbon and under Main Tabs, select the Developer check box.

Next, Press Alt+F11 to open the VBA editor, then create "New Module" by selecting it from the drop down show here:

[image]

Paste the following code into the new window that opens. (it looks like a lot, but there isn't too much to it once you start working with it)

```
    'The following Function helps Excel identify if a character is a letter or not
Function IsLetter(strValue As String) As Boolean
    Dim intPos As Integer
    For intPos = 1 To Len(strValue)
        Select Case Asc(Mid(strValue, intPos, 1))
            Case 65 To 90, 97 To 122
                IsLetter = True
            Case Else
                IsLetter = False
                Exit For
        End Select
    Next
End Function
'The following function helps Excel identify if a character is a special character, like #, @, and !
Function IsSpecial(strValue As String) As Boolean
    Dim intPos As Integer
    For intPos = 1 To Len(strValue)
        Select Case Asc(Mid(strValue, intPos, 1))
            Case 33 To 47, 58 To 64, 91 To 96, 123 To 126
                IsSpecial = True
            Case Else
                IsSpecial = False
                Exit For
        End Select
    Next
End Function
'This is the Macro that will change the colors of characters in your selected range
Public Sub ColorText()
'the next 3 lines set abbreviations as certain kinds of things. Long is a number or integer, Ranges are cell selections
Dim lng As Long
Dim rng As Range
Dim cl As Range
'The next line sets the range of cells to change colors in to whatever cells you have selected on the sheet
    Set rng = Selection
'This section loops through each cell in your selection and checks each character in the cell.
    For Each cl In rng.Cells
    For lng = 1 To Len(cl.Value)
        With cl.Characters(lng, 1)
'First the code checks for letters and keeps them black
        If IsLetter(.Text) Then
            .Font.ColorIndex = 1 'change this number to change the color
        
'Next it checks for Special Characters and colors them Blue
        ElseIf IsSpecial(.Text) Then
            .Font.ColorIndex = 41
        
'If a character is not a letter or a special, it must be a number, so it colors numbers red
        Else
            .Font.ColorIndex = 3
        
        End If
        End With
    Next lng    'this moves the code to the next character
  Next cl       'once all the characters are checked, this moves the code to the next cell
End Sub         'once all the selected cells have been run through, this ends the code
```

Your Module should look [like this now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFBic.png).

Now you're ready to start changing colors.
First, select all the cells you want to change colors on.

[image]

Next, open your Developer tab (1) and click on the Macros button (2):

[image]

You should see your ColorText macro. Select it and click on Run

[image]

And your text should be colored based on the character type!

[image]

This will change the color of characters in cells that are selected. So, you can select an entire column, or individual cells.

[image]

If you ever want to mess with the code, simply press Alt+F11 to open the vba editor. You'll need to double click on Module 1 to open it.

To change the colors in the VBA, refer to [this chart](http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/excel/colors.htm) for color options and corresponding numbers.

I hope this helps. You could even assign this macro to a [button](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/assign-a-macro-to-a-button-728c83ec-61d0-40bd-b6ba-927f84eb5d2c) or [custom keyboard shortcut](https://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s139/short-cut-key-macros-excel.htm).

Comment: Hi @jrichall . Thank you very much for your detailed and didactic response. Actually this code works very well, but now I have other doubts:

I see that the code works when the values are written directly in the cell but not when they come from the result of a formula (for example, the cell in question is the concatenation of the content of other cells and those that form the password `CONCATENATE (B2; B3; B4)`.

What value should be changed in the code in that case? Because I tried it and it throws error 1004, pointing to the line `If IsLetter (.Text) Then`